# How can I solve a three-dimensional Gross-Pitaevskii equation?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method

I want to solve a three-dimensional Gross-Pitaevskii equation with an uniform potential. The related papers are *[Emergence of a Turbulent Cascade in a Quantum Gas](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.01271.pdf)* and *[Synthetic dissipation and cascade fluxes in a turbulent quantum gas](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.07564.pdf)*.

The code I tried was

```
hbar = 1;

kB = 1.380649*10^-23;
\[Mu] = 1;(*2 10^-9 kB;*)
\[Xi] = 1;(*1.2 10^-6;*)

Udepth = 30 \[Mu];
Uz = 27/1.2 \[Xi];
UR = 16/1.2 \[Xi];

N0 = 1. 10^5;
n0 = N0/(Pi UR^2 Uz);
g = \[Mu]/n0;
\[CapitalDelta]U = \[Mu]; (*shaking amplitude*)
\[Omega]shaking =
 2 Pi 8;

Lx = 40 \[Xi]; Ly = 40 \[Xi]; Lz = 40 \[Xi];
x0 = Lx;
M = 1;
Vtrap[x_, y_, z_, t_] :=
 If[x^2 + y^2 < UR && -Uz/2 < z < Uz/2, 0,
   Udepth] + \[CapitalDelta]U Sin[\[Omega]shaking t] z/Uz
eqs = { D[\[Psi]1[t, x, y, z],
     t] == ((-g n0 Laplacian[\[Psi]1[t, x, y, z], {x, y,
         z}]) + (Vtrap[x, y, z, t] +
        g (Abs[\[Psi]1[t, x, y, z]]^2)) \[Psi]1[t, x, y, z])/(
    I g n0 hbar)};
bc = {\[Psi]1[0, x, y, z] ==
    Exp[-x^2/(10 \[Xi])^2] Exp[-y^2/(10 \[Xi])^2] Exp[-z^2/(10 \
\[Xi])^2](*1/Sqrt[rcx rcy Pi]Exp[-x^2/rcx^2/2]Exp[-y^2/rcy^2/2]*),
   DirichletCondition[\[Psi]1[t, x, y, z] == 0, True]};
solv = NDSolve[{eqs, bc}, \[Psi]1, {t, 0, 0.5}, {x, -Lx/2,
   Lx/2}, {y, -Ly/2, Ly/2}, {z, -Lz/2, Lz/2},
    Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", \
{"SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}}}]
```

But this costs too much time and can not output. What should I do?

Comment: You expect a real solution `\[Psi]1`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann No. The wavefunction can be a complex one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After proper normalization we have

```
hbar = 1;

kB = 1.380649*10^-23;
\[Mu] = 1;(*2 10^-9 kB;*)
\[Xi] = 1;(*1.2 10^-6;*)

Udepth = 30 \[Mu];
Uz = 27/1.2 \[Xi];
UR = 16/1.2 \[Xi];

N0 = 1. 10^5;
n0 = N0/(Pi UR^2 Uz);
g = \[Mu]/n0;
\[CapitalDelta]U = \[Mu]; (*shaking amplitude*)
\[Omega]shaking = 2 Pi 8;

Lx = 40 \[Xi]; Ly = 40 \[Xi]; Lz = 40 \[Xi];
x0 = Lx; g1 = g/(g n0 );
M = 1;
Vtrap[x_, y_, z_, t_] := 
 If[x^2 + y^2 < UR && -Uz/2 < z < Uz/2, 0, 
   Udepth] + \[CapitalDelta]U Sin[\[Omega]shaking t] z/(Uz g n0)
eqs = {I hbar D[\[Psi]1[t, x, y, z], 
      t] == ((-Laplacian[\[Psi]1[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}]) + (Vtrap[x, 
          y, z, t] + g1 (Abs[\[Psi]1[t, x, y, z]]^2)) \[Psi]1[t, x, y,
         z])};
bc = {\[Psi]1[0, x, y, z] == 
    Exp[-x^2/(10 \[Xi])^2] Exp[-y^2/(10 \[Xi])^2] Exp[-z^2/(10 \
\[Xi])^2](*1/Sqrt[rcx rcy Pi]Exp[-x^2/rcx^2/2]Exp[-y^2/rcy^2/2]*), 
   DirichletCondition[\[Psi]1[t, x, y, z] == 0, True]};

solv = NDSolve[{eqs, bc}, \[Psi]1, {t, 0, 0.5}, {x, -Lx/2, 
   Lx/2}, {y, -Ly/2, Ly/2}, {z, -Lz/2, Lz/2}]
```

Visualization

```
Table[Plot3D[
  Evaluate[Abs[\[Psi]1[t, 0, y, z] /. solv[[1]]]], {y, -Ly/2, 
   Ly/2}, {z, -Lz/2, Lz/2}, PlotLabel -> t, 
  ColorFunction -> "ArmyColors", Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All], {t, 
  0, .5, .1}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Alex And can I ask you how much time this code takes  in your computer?

Comment: Ah, I see that time is about 5771.71 s. Did you ask about time optimization?

Comment: Yeah,@Alex. After a whole night, the updated code is still running in my computer(Macbook pro 13.3' M1, 16G+512G ). So what is the possible reason here? Is this issue very dependent on the performance of the computer? And can I ask you how much memory do you use?

Comment: And the vesion is mathematica 13.0.

Comment: May be solution depends on version? In my case `$Version` is  13.2.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 27, 2023).  Machine has 32 GiB physical memory, and 33.85 GiB virtual memory.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Very interesting answer! I tried to understand the normalization . Perhaps righthand side of your pde should $\text{$\psi $1}(t,x,y,z) \left(\text{g1} | \text{$\psi $1}(t,x,y,z)|
   ^2+\frac{\text{g1} \text{Vtrap}(x,y,z,t)}{g}\right)-\nabla
   _{\{x,y,z\}}^2\text{$\psi $1}(t,x,y,z)$ be I think

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Please, pay attention that in my code `Vtrap[x_, y_, z_, t_] := 
 If[x^2 + y^2 < UR && -Uz/2 < z < Uz/2, 0, 
   Udepth] + \[CapitalDelta]U Sin[\[Omega]shaking t] z/(Uz g n0)`, so it been normalized before.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks, I got it

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks, I will try.

Comment: Hi @AlexTrounev, to further speed up the calculation, what should we do? How about increasing the step size? And how to control that? Thanks!

Comment: @so_sure The question is what do you try to simulate with this model?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Firstly, I want to reproduce the resluts in the article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.01271.pdf as mentioned above.

Comment: @so_sure They proposed numerical method as follows. "We perform numerical simulations on a cubic grid of 256^3 points. Using a symmetrised split-step Fourier method we evolve the Bose field in time steps of 10 µs for up to 4 s. The calculations are performed at FP32 precision on an NVIDIA GeForce GTX TITAN X graphics card, and we achieve a running time of under 30 min for simulating each 1 s of dynamics". This is very far from `NDSolve` algorithm.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yes. Although the details may be different, shouldn't the result be the same qualitatively？

Comment: @so_sure Maybe results gonna be the same. Could you try to compute up to t=10?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have tried up to t=300, but the reslut is still incorrect. The details can be found in [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282351/solving-a-three-dimensional-gross-pitaevskii-equation) I posted. Hope you can give me some sugestions, Thanks!